# Add (...) to hash entries over certain character limit in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, hash

I'm very new to Ruby and searching for a solution.

Essentially I have a hash in the form of [0 > String, 1 > String] etc.

I want to run a loop which can count the characters in the strings in the hashes, should it reach a limit, the end of the string should be cut at that point and replaced with '...'

**Example:**

```
Say I set my character count at 10:

Hello World!

Would shorten to:

Hello Worl...
```

May be worth noting that this hash is created from an array, as such if it is deemed wiser to do it before the hash conversion, that would also be fine. Any advice is hugely appreciated.

Comment: so your hash is like this: `{0 => String, 1 => String}`?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Have you solved it for a single string, i.e. without a hash?

Comment: `Hello Worl...` is a longer string than `Hello World!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using ActiveSupport's Truncate Method

If you're willing to mix in methods from the [ActiveSupport gem](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activesupport) such as [String#truncate](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-truncate), this is trivial. For example:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/string/filters'

'Hello World!'.truncate 10
#=> "Hello W..."
```

Note that the #truncate method counts the ellipsis as three characters (one for each period in the ellipsis) towards the total character count. Bump your count by three characters (e.g. 13 instead of 10) if you actually want 10 characters before the ellipsis rather than including it.

Comment: Thanks, this actually made stuff quite easy in the end. I'm polling the hash data using a RAND for the end-view. After some thought I realised I didn't need to process the batch but just as it comes (there is only between 5 and 15 per days so it's not too expensive). Works well and was simple, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not beautiful, but it does what you're asking:

```
hash = {
  0 => 'hello world',
  1 => 'hello'
}

hash.each_pair do |key, value|
  p key: key
  p value: value.length > 10 ? value[0..9] + '...' : value
end
```

you could also make a method to truncate the string, like this:

```
def truncate(string, truncate_after)
  return string if string.length < truncate_after

  string[0..(truncate_after - 1)] + '...'
end
```